# Testing against directory traversal

Tags: java, url, path, path-traversal

I was reading about testing against directory traversal on this website: https://wiki.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_Directory_traversal/file_include_(OTG-AUTHZ-001)

And at the end it says

> Testing for the flaw is achieved by:

```
file=....//....//boot.ini 
file=....\\....\\boot.ini 
file= ..\..\boot.ini
```

But what does `....\\ or ..../` actually achieve? Javas URI method "normalize()" does not care about it and when I try it on a Windows machine nothing happens.

Comment: This is not a test for the `URI.normalize()` method. The first line is a test input for the code sample just above: `filename = Request.QueryString(“file”); Replace(filename, “/”,”\”); Replace(filename, “..\”,””);` which is "normalized" to `..\..\boot.ini`. That clearly shows that the code sample just above does **not** protect against directory traversal attacks.

Comment: Ah okay I misunderstood, thanks for the clarification.